# Scipy function that generate Root locus of Linear Time Invariant Systems

Tags: python, scipy

Does anyone out there know if there is some Scipy function that plots the Root Locus of LTIs? I found nothing in the package scipy.signal.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is. You can use [`python-control`](https://github.com/python-control/python-control) control systems library developed by Richard Murray et al. It uses a matlab-like syntax and also has a matlab compatibility option.

```
import control as cnt
G = cnt.tf([1,-2,-3],[1,2,1])
cnt.rlocus(G);
```

will give

[image]

Notice the final semicolon to suppress the output on the terminal. I don't know why they opted out for that behavior.

---

Shameless plug: I'm also developing the [`harold`](https://github.com/ilayn/harold) library in a rather orthogonal direction that is away from matlab-like syntax for hopefully a more intuitive control engineering tool. The alpha release is now on [`PyPI`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/harold) and the documentation is on [`ReadTheDocs`](http://harold.readthedocs.org/) (see the *module index* link for the command reference).

There is still a lot to do before it becomes a proper library. On the positive side, you won't need any explicit FORTRAN libraries or external tools.

Moreover, `harold` uses more up-to-date algorithms than matlab at certain places and that's basically what I'm continuously testing.

I'd like to use this opportunity to encourage any contributions/bug reports/insulting emails/feature requests.

Comment: Awesome, @percusse. Thanks for your answer. I thought very interesting your ideia of a library for control systems that have a more flexible syntax than MatLab. I would love to help but still have little experience with python programming, and I believe it still would not be able to perform very complex tasks. But, if I can help in something, I'm available =).

Comment: @rnt_42 My pleasure. I am desperately trying to finish a primitive documentation. Once it is in place, you can just install and beat the hell out of it. That would hopefully reveal those nasty bugs lurking around. I'm also pretty average programmer too so no worries. Luckily most of our stuff is number-crunching but not deep programming. But I'm pretty familiar with control theory which is why I'm doing this ridiculous initiative because I believe our field is outdating itself with matlab from the start. Somebody has to do something ;) I have a simple wiki page for motivation on github *why*.